# ¿Cómo instalar Selenium en una version específica de Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

Tengo varias versiones de Python instaladas en mi pc. En la version 2.7 , tengo Selenium instalado. En la version 3.4 no, y lo quiero instalar. Voy a la carpeta Python 3.4 y ejecuto pip install selenium y me dice

```
Requirement already satisfied: Selenium in c:\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

Cómo tengo que hacer para que me lo instale en la versión 3.4?

Comment: Instala el paquete mediante pip de la versión en la que quieras instalar, usando  Python Launcher: `py -3.4 -m pip install selenium`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias probar con:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Comment: No se porque te votaron negativo si me funciono.

Comment: Hola karton, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías añadir algo más de detalle a la publicación (p.e. qué hace ese comando). Lee [answer] para más información.